# Change Jquery standart effects with Flux-Slider effects

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-effects, flux

This my code:

```
        $("#headerimg" + currentContainer).fadeOut(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#headertxt").css({"display" : "block"});
            animating = false;
        }, 500);
    });
};
```

But i don't want this effect (**fadeOut**), i want to use Flux-Slider's effects. (Example: **Warp**)
I didn't change this code for new effect. 
How do I change this?

Answer (score 0):

Call to the Warp effect instead of fadeOut by creating a link for it.

```
<ul id="sliderOptions">
    <li><a href="#warp">View next</a></li>
</ul>
```